# Meteor.logout() waiting on server response

Tags: meteor

Looking at the source for Meteor.logout(), the call waits for the server to respond before marking the user as logged out on the client. What is the reasoning for the wait? Would something break if makeClientLoggedOut() was called immediately?

```
Meteor.logout = function (callback) {
  Meteor.apply('logout', [], {wait: true}, function(error, result) {
    if (error) {
      callback && callback(error);
    } else {
      makeClientLoggedOut();
      callback && callback();
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: This is a typical pattern for asynchronous method call. Since `logout` is a remote method, you need to wait to make sure this method was successfully executed on the server.

Comment: @apendua except Meteor is usually all about latency compensation, meaning things happen on the client first, and then revert later if the server rejects it.

Comment: @BenjaminRH fine, but does legacy compensation makes any sense when you're trying to logout?

Comment: Yeah, I think you could argue that **latency** compensation makes sense when you're trying to logout. It's all about making it appear fast, why should that be any different?

Comment: Because then user could think that he's actually logged out and his data is purged, and thus he'd close the tab, while Meteor still needs to do some cleanup.